# wxPython Manual Scroll of panel ScrolledPanel failing with wx.Grid

Tags: python, wxpython

I've created a panel thats derived from wx.lib.scrolledpanel. I could scroll on it fine with my mousewheel until I put a grid into the panel. Now when the mouse cursor is on top of the grid, the scroll stopped working, and would start working again if i moved the cursor outside of the grid.

I figured the easiest solution after searching and searching was to just manually capture the mousewheel event and scroll the panel manually. I bound this handler to wx.EVT_MOUSEWHEEL inside my wx.App object

```
class Wx_app(wx.App):

    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__(clearSigInt=True)
        self.frame = MyFrame(None, pos=(0,0), size=(1900, 1100))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MOUSEWHEEL, self.on_mouse_wheel)

    def on_mouse_wheel(self, e):

        # get the current scroll pos, is tuple with x as first val, y as second val
        pos = self.frame.panel.CalcUnscrolledPosition(0, 0)
        y_pos = pos[1]

        # detemrine if user is scrolling up or down
        if e.GetWheelRotation() > 0:

            # user is scrolling up
            print("UP")
            self.frame.panel.Scroll(0, y_pos + 10)

        else:

            # user is scrolling down
            print("DOWN")
            self.frame.panel.Scroll(0, y_pos - 10)
```

This code works when i try to scroll down, but when i try to scroll back up with the the mousewheel nothing happens, even though "UP" registers in my terminal. Also i would think up should be y_pos - 10 and not y_pos + 10, but then the wheel scrolls in the opposite direction you would expect. What am I doing wrong? Perhaps i'm not getting the correct existing position in the first place, but CalcUnscrolledPosition is the only thing I could find that could maybe do that. I'm new to Python please explain it like I'm a 5 year old. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your immediate issue is that `Up` would be `Y - 10` and `Down` would be `Y + 10`.
You need to go further up (less y) or further down (more y).

You also may well be comparing Apples with Oranges, when relying on the position as returned from the mouse event and how that relates to the position within the scrolled window.

The crux of this is that both the scrolledpanel `and` the grid are scrollable widgets.
Your issue seems to be that your grid is not of sufficent size to show the grid's scrollbars, thus causing confusion.

You can force the scrollbars on the grid and size it so that it is obvious that there are two sets of scrollbars and hopefully your users will work it out.

Here is a sample grid in a scrolled panel to play with (ignore the bound functions, they were there because initially I misunderstood your issue, thinking that you wanted manual scrolling within the grid)

```
import wx
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel
import wx.grid

class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs) 
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.fileFormPanel = FileFormPanel(self)
        self.sizer.Add(self.fileFormPanel, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)

class FileFormPanel(wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel.__init__(self, parent)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        # Create a wxGrid object
        self.grid = wx.grid.Grid(self, -1, size=(300,480))
        self.grid.CreateGrid(5, 10)
        self.grid.SetRowLabelSize(1)
        self.grid.SetDefaultColSize(120)
        self.grid.SetColSize(0, 50)
        self.grid.ShowScrollbars(True, True)
        for j in range(5):
            for k in range(10):
                self.grid.SetCellValue(j, k, str(k))

        text = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, value="Some text")

        sizer.Add(self.grid)
        sizer.Add(text)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.SetupScrolling()

        #self.grid.Bind(wx.EVT_MOUSEWHEEL, self.OnGrid)
        #self.Bind(wx.EVT_MOUSEWHEEL, self.OnScroll)
        #self.grid.Bind(wx.grid.EVT_GRID_SELECT_CELL, self.OnSelect)

#    def OnGrid(self, event):
#        obj = event.GetEventObject()
#        if event.WheelRotation > 0:
#            self.grid.MoveCursorUp(False)
#        else:
#            self.grid.MoveCursorDown(False)
#
#    def OnSelect(self, event):
#        obj = event.GetEventObject()
#        r = event.GetRow()
#        c = event.GetCol()
#        self.grid.MakeCellVisible(r,c)
#        event.Skip()
#
#    def OnScroll(self, event):
#        print("window scroll")
#        event.Skip()

class DemoFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent = None, size = (400, 400))
        MyPanel(self)

class App(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = DemoFrame()
        self.frame.Show()
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)

        return True

app = App()
app.MainLoop()
```

[image]